# Matrix multiplication using one-dimensionsal arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I've been having some troubles multiplying due matrix (in form of  two, one-dimensional arrays) in C. No variables can be created nor deleted.

The correct result should be: http://s32.postimg.org/nrkigh2l1/IMG_20160516_183316.jpg

The print cycles should be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    unsigned int m = 3;                              // first matrix number of rows
    unsigned int n = 2;                              // first matrix number of columns
    unsigned int k = 4;                              // second matrix number of columns
    short int mat1[] = { -1,-2,   4, 5,   4, -2 };   // first matrix (3x2)
    short int mat2[] = { 2, 0, 0, 0,   0, 2, 0, 0 }; // second matrix 2x4)
    int mat3[1024];                                  // final matrix (3x4)




     // printing final matrix
    unsigned int i, j, h;
    printf("Final matrix:\n");
    for (i = h = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++, h++)
            printf("%6d ", mat3[h]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried and indicate where you think the problem is.

Comment: I can't understand how to use the index (number of rows and columns) to slide across the matrix.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163948/multiplying-two-matrices-with-different-dimensions) and express indexes in terms of single dimensional arrays. If you have `mat1[3][2]`, then do just like in your declaration...

Comment: Solve this on paper using a pencil first. Name rows an columns and listen to yourself while solving this.

Comment: `[0][0]->[0]; [0][1]->[1]; [1][0]->[2];` etc. in a 3*2 matrix.

Comment: I get this error: "expression must have pointer to object type"
http://s32.postimg.org/p0tfi8sph/Screen_Shot_2016_05_16_at_19_13_19.png

Comment: @Andr1x: `mat3` still is a 1D-array. It's elements cannot be addressed by a 2D-index. You need to transform back an elements 2D-position to the corresponding 1D-addressable element of `mat3`.

Answer (score -1):

Others have shown how to multiply matrices of different dimensions. All you need to do is to convert the code to access a 1D vector as a 2D matrix.

So, given the [hypothetical] matrix:

```
#define XDIM    10
#define YDIM    5
int mtx[YDIM][XDIM];
```

To convert this to a vector:

```
int vec[YDIM * XDIM];
```

To access an element, instead of:

```
mtx[ypos][xpos]
```

Use:

```
vec[(ypos * XDIM) + xpos]
```

You can repeat this technique using different values for the different matrices.